# Calculating $\int_0^\infty ({ae^{-jw}})^t \ dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know how to calculate $\int_0^\infty e^{-jwt} \ dt$ from $0$ to infinity but how do you deal with that extra $a^t$ term?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Perhaps tell us how you want to compute it?  Some summation method?  I ask since $\int_0^\infty e^{-j\omega t}\,dt$ diverges for real $\omega$.  But then taking $|a|<1$ in your integral will give you convergence.

Comment: mod a is less than one

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$a^t=e^{t\ln(a)}$$ $$$$$$$$

Comment: i am getting 1/(jw-ln a) as the result using your hint. the answer i should get is 1/(1-(a(e^-jw))). how do i get the answer in this form?